# K&R exercise 1-19, reverse line

Tags: beginner, c, strings, io

I've just started to read K&R and currently, I'm dealing with problem 1-19:

> Write a function `reverse(s)` that reverses the character string `s`. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time.

Here is what I've implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000

void reverseLine(char reversedLine[], char line[], int lineSize);

int main(void) {

    int c;
    int i = 0;

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        line[i++] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n')
        line[i++] = '\0';

    int realSize = i;
    char reversedLine[realSize];

    reverseLine(reversedLine, line, realSize);
    printf("%s\n", reversedLine);

    return 0;
}

void reverseLine(char reversedLine[], char line[], int lineSize){
    int j, k;
    for(j = lineSize - 2, k = 0; j >= 0; j--, k++){
        reversedLine[k] = line[j];
    }
    reversedLine[k] = '\0';
}
```

I'm having problems on grasping the spirit exactly as I am supposed to be. So, any help to improve my solution will be appreciated!

Comment: "the solution I implemented for problem 1-19" Please include a problem description.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Edited it now.

Comment: @SamOnela That's not how duplicates work on Code Review. [Please read the relevant meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/52915) or find us in chat.

Comment: Sorry yeah just found that...

Comment: It looks like `reversedline` is allocated one character larger than it needs to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good initial code.

---

1. No protection against buffer overflow.

   ```
   char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
     if (i < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {  // add
       line[i++] = c;
     }
   }
   ```
2. No check for "too long a line"

   ```
   // add test
   if (i  == MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Input too long.\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   ```
3. Always add the null character termination

   ```
   // if (c == '\n')  // comment out line
   line[i++] = '\0';
   ```
4. Code *looks* wrong with the `- 2`, yet it appears code functions correctly.  The 2-ness needs explaining.  Below is a `size_t` version.  Note use of `const`.

   ```
   void reverseLine(char reversedLine[], const char line[], size_t lineSize){
     if (lineSize > 0) {
       size_t lineLen = lineSize - 1;
       size_t i;
       for (i = 0; i < lineLen; i++) {
         reversedLine[i] = line[lineLen - i];
       }
       reversedLine[i] = '\0';
     }
   }
   ```
5. Minor: for array sizing and indexing `size_t` is the best type.  `int` may be too narrow in extreme cases.  Yet keep in mind that `size_t` is some unsigned type.
6. Minor: "length" vs "size":  When these two are applied to *strings*, using "size" to refer to the array *size* of the *string* and "length" as the value return from `strlen()` adds clarity.  IMO, `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` should be `LINE_SIZE` or stay with `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` and use `char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1]; ...  if (i < sizeof line) { ... if (i == sizeof line) {`.

---

Advanced issue: Overlap

```
void reverseLine(char reversedLine[], char line[], int lineSize);
```

Strictly speaking, the function, `reverseLine()` does not, by its declaration, indicate that `reversedLine[]` and `lineSize[]` should not overlap.  It could fail in bizarre ways should they overlap.

C provides `restrict` to 1) indicate pointers should not point to overlapped data and 2) allow the compiler to perform additional optimizations that require that assumption.

```
// [] form also shifted to * form
void reverseLine(char * restrict reversedLine, const char * restrict line, int lineSize);
```

Alternatively code could be re-written to cope with overlapped buffers.  I'll leave that as an exercise.

---

Design idea:  In C, many of the basic *string* functions assume the destination array is big enough.  As the standard library functions are crafted for performance, checking size allocation is left as a responsibility to the caller.

`reverseLine()` could be re-designed to do that test.  Instead of leaving the size test to the caller, consider that `reverseLine()` is not a basic building block and it could check for sufficient memory.  As with such things, error handling is an important, but for now, TBD consideration.

```
// rLineSize is the space available at `rLine`
// The length of the string pointed to by `line` can use `strlen()`
void reverseLine2(char * restrict rLine, size_t rLineSize, const char * restrict line) { 
  size_t lineSize = strlen(line) + 1;
  if (lineSize > rLineSize) Handle_Error();
  ...
```

Comment: I had no idea about that much number of missing points standing out in my code. Those are quite new and interesting stuff to me. I'll examine your comment time-to-time since I've just started to study C :) Thank you for your time and detailed explanation!

Comment: @SaidBuyukarslan Additional idea:  Write a stand-along function for  user input rather than code in `main()`.  Modularize code for code re-use.